# How to save 2 times different data in the same field of DB table? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

This is a little hard to explain, but I'm gonna put it the easiest possible way.

I've a form with 1 field repeated 2 times to save 2 different times in the same submit.

The purpose is to save those 2 times repeated fields in 2 different rows of the DB at the same time.

Why that structure? I don't know, but this is how it is created the form and the table, and it cannot be modified.

Any way to do it? Modifying the model? The controller maybe? Help Laravel gurus.

##### `DB Structure`

> - ID (Primary Key, AUTOINCREMENT)
> - Data (String)

##### `DataController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\data;

use App\Data;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('data', ['Data' => new Data()]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Data::create($request->validated());
    }
}
```

##### `Data.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Data extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_data';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'data'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

##### `data.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Send Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        {{-- Data in field 1 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
        </div>

        {{-- Data in field 2 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why dont you just call ```Data::create($request->validated());``` twice?

Comment: Did you try to do it with json? `json_decode($dates)` & `json_encode($dates)`?

Comment: I tried too Y.Y but it didn't work because the 2 data field are gonna be different, and if I do that it gonna save 2 times the last data field, not the first one and then the second one.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin How did it works??

Comment: @ElcondeLucanor you will add JSON data to DB, give me time I will add an answer with my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will add JSON to DB
Just follow steps

```
{{-- At blade --}
{{-- Data in field 1 in DB --}
<div>
    <input type="text" name="data[]" id="data"> <!-- you should add[] to return array of data -->
</div>

{{-- Data in field 2 in DB --}
<div>
   <input type="text" name="data[]" id="data">
</div>
```

The next step

```
// At controller
$request->validate([
   'data.*' => ['required', 'date'], // your validation
]);
$json = json_encode($request->get('data'));
Data::create(['data' => $json]);
```

The next step is when you call data from the database

```
// Model (Data)
// We change from json to array (you can do anything here like chage date format)
public function getDataAttribute()
{
   return json_decode($this->data);
}
```

The last step

```
//anywhere
$model->data[0]
$model->data[1]
```

NOTE you can do want with a different key just at HTML change names `data1`, `data2` If you want to do it just tell me and I will edit the answer.

Another note: I did not try this code, If anything wrong happens please tell me to know.

Happy Coding.

Comment: The last step code where should I put? In controller? In blade?

Comment: @ElcondeLucanor Anywhere I meant like a controller or a blade.